# Power BI Visualisation and Formating

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Hi There I'm quite new to Power BI wanted to ask some advice on a Approach for visualising some data.

1) I Would like to Group together some values to display as a indicator (green or red) depending on the value.

for example: 
VM Running= green
VM Deallocated= red

2) and to also list all machine names from the dataset into the report under each indicator

and example of the actual Test data is below i would like to visualise:

[image: Test Data]

and an example of the visualisation i want to create:

[image: An Example Visualisation]

Any Advice on Approach or how to achieve this in MS PowerBI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get exactly what you want, I think you would need to create your own [custom visual](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/custom-visuals/).

---

Since creating a custom visual takes some time to figure out, I explored options with existing resources and I was able to create something close-ish to what you want. To get the custom visual into your report, click on "Home" -> "From Store" (in the Custom Visuals group)

[image: Custom Visual]

In the dialog that pops up, search for "dot plot" and click on "Add" by the "Dot Plot by OKViz" visual.

[image: Dot Plot]

You will now see a new icon in the visualization panel.

[image: New visualization]

Before we use that visualization, let's look at the data I used. I created some sample data similar in structure to yours and then added one column using the below DAX formula.

```
Value = RANKX(Attendance, Attendance[Class],, ASC, Dense)
```

[image: Data]

Now we create a new dot plot and fill in the fields as show below.

[image: Fields]

That results in something that looks like this.

[image: Visual]

You can then change the black circles to red, by clicking on the paint roller icon between the Visualizations panel and the data panel.

[image: New color]

From there, it is up to you how you want to present it. I did some additional tweaking to the formatting and added some cards for the class name (configured as shown below)

[image: Cards]

In the end, it could look something like this.

[image: Results]

---

You could also split it up by class (group) and get something that looks like this.

[image: Other Result]

Comment: Just tried this in my environment and works perfectly well!,  thanks a lot for this is the best solution!.

Comment: @BenAhm, I'm glad I could help.